# Capture iphone REST requests

Tags: iphone, rest, networking, wireshark

I want to capture POST/GET requests sent by my iPhone. I tried to connect my macbook to Lan and share the connection over Wifi. I connected to the shared wifi with my iPhone and started wireShark. It didin't detect any packet from my phone on both interfaces, wifi and land.

I found a software called Brup. I started it as a proxy on my mac and configured the ip adress of the mac as a proxy on my iphone. It worked with some apps but the most of them showed me a message saying that it was not possible to establisch a secure communication with their server.

Is it not possible to see what REST requests are the apps using to communicate with their servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool called mitmproxy (https://mitmproxy.org/) wich can help you to intercept all requests made by apps using standard http/https. You need to install its CA certificate into your phone prior but it is very simple, just navigate to special address mitm.it and click on appropriate logo for your system. Works with most of the apps I have tried. It generates temporary self signed SSL certificates for the websites/rest endpoints you visit and thus allows to see encrypted communications between apps and their servers.

But it is not capable of intercepting iOS system services communications which do not use HTTP proxy settings and always use direct connections on ports other than 443. You can intercept wifi packages using wireshark (just follow the instructions on their website and do not forget to put your wifi network card into monitor mode and reconnect to the network - https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Turning_on_monitor_mode) but you will not see what's inside encrypted SSL packages, so the only usefull information from there are destination addresses and ports.

To capture iOS system communications you need to use custom TCP proxy similar to how mitmproxy works and somehow route all packages from the device through your proxy. Here is another usefull tool to start with in this task: https://blog.heckel.xyz/2013/08/04/use-sslsplit-to-transparently-sniff-tls-ssl-connections/

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I downloaded mitproxy.org and when I executed it it opened two terminals, and one of them was showing the content of my electrum wallets folder. I suspect the program to contain a malicious code. 
I tried the steps by using Brup and it worked. However that dose not work with some apps that uses https. Do they detect the proxy? is there any method to make them work?

Comment: I suggest to install and make mitmproxy work. It is really useful tool and it works for all apps I have tried so far. Looks like you have some virus on your PC. Try to cleanup it first. I have never used Brup and cannot suggest about it.

Comment: Ok thank you but I suggest to evereyone to be very carful, I highly suspect mitproxy to contain a malware. It also dose not work with the apps that do not work with Brup(whatsapp, facebook...)

Answer (score -1):

I am using Stream, which do not need any proxy settings. Just sniff https traffic on iOS side (without my MBP). https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stream/id1312141691?mt=8